# Nested commands in single bash line

Tags: linux, bash, pipe, mutt

Using bash, how do I send the output file from one command to be used as a variable in the second command, in one line?

I'm trying to use streamer and mutt to take a picture using my webcam and then email it to an email address. I've got as far as the below, but not sure how to tell mutt to use the file created in the previous (streamer) command.

```
streamer -o image.jpg && echo "email body" | mutt -a (file from previous command) -s Subject -- recipient@email.com
```

Comment: If the name of the file from the previous command is `image.jpg` then just use that name. Or is the output coming from the standard output of the prior command?

Comment: What isn't working? Provide more details. Your syntax looks fine.

Comment: I would like mutt to take the output file from the previous command, regardless of the file name. What I want to do is create a shortcut on my Ubuntu desktop that executes this command (as a security feature but keen to learn how this works anyway). However, if this command is executed multiple times then the    image.jpg    file will be overwritten or prompted to overwrite which is what I want to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand how `streamer` works, you can use process substitution:

```
echo "email body" | mail -a <( streamer )
```

The shell provides a file name for the `-a` option which `mail` can then read to access the standard output of `streamer`.

Otherwise, just use the name as suggested by `mbratch`, since the pipeline with mail will not run until `streamer` completes successfully:

```
streamer -o image.jpg && echo "email body" | mail -a image.jpg
```

or, using some knowledge about the command line to avoid typing `image.jpg` twice, use

```
streamer -o image.jpg && echo "email body" | mail -a !#:2
```

to reuse the 3rd word (counting from 0) of the current command line to grab the name of the file `streamer` uses for output.

Comment: I tried substituting and Mutt coughed up errors saying it couldn't attach the physical webcam device (/dev/fd/63) to the email. I'll try the other suggestions, thanks!

Comment: `/dev/fd/63` isn't the web cam, but the file descriptor that the shell allocates for `streamer`. It appears `mutt` tries to use the file in a way that isn't compatible with how process substitution works.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no such way.

What you could do is the following

```
OUTPUT_FILE="image.jpg"; streamer -o ${OUTPUT_FILE} && echo "email body" | mutt -a ${OUTPUT_FILE} -s Subject -- recipient@email.com
```

In your example the output file name is even static, so you could just hardcode it.

Comment: Thanks, this is useful. Wasn't sure how you declared a variable on the command line, it's as simple as that!